# Bootstrap input group button keeps wrapping to 2nd line in a modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

For some reason.. the button in the input-group keeps wrapping to the 2nd line.. the only way I can force it to stay on the 1st line is to use CSS to make the width 80% for example.  But then the spacing seems off between the 4 elements..

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?  I dont even know why it's wrapping to the 2nd line.. maybe because I'm using this in a Modal?

EDIT: how it looks like http://imgur.com/sfWqATl

```
<!--3rd row-->
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        stuff...
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <small>Logo 1 ID / File Path</small>
            <br />
            <div>
                <input type="file" data-file="headline.contents.logo1path" id="logoPath1" class="hidden" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" type="button"></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        stuff...
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        stuff...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have gotten a little mixed up in setting up the classes and elements to chain correctly based on the documentation.  I re-wrote some of the code to model it from the bootstrap website, and it appears to work fine:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <small>Logo 1 ID / File Path</small>
    <input type="file" data-file="headline.contents.logo1path" id="logoPath1" class="hidden" />
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the example here: http://www.bootply.com/EHvB2rn9YW